# return a mysql table column according to column conditions

Tags: mysql, row

i have a table containing route id's for buses with bus stops..
like below..

```
    route_id                  stop_name
     1234                      stop1
     1234                      stop2
     1235                      stop7
     1235                      stop8
```

i want a route_id that contains both stop1 and stop2 (for stop1 and stop2 i would like to get 1234)

i wrote this query..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(route_id) 
FROM bus_stops 
WHERE stops='stop1' AND stops='stop2'
```

but it returned an empty set.

Comment: Try to use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: but if am using OR i think it will not satisfy both(stops) conditions...

Comment: Switching to OR doesn't help him either -- that won't guarantee he gets a route_id that stops at BOTH stops, just all the routes that pass through either stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, but I don't promise it's the best or most elegant solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT route_id FROM myTable AS myAlias
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE route_id = myAlias.route_id AND stop_name = 'stop1' )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE route_id = myAlias.route_id AND stop_name = 'stop2' )
```

Actually, I don't even promise it's tested -- but using subqueries similar to those ought to get you there.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
select distint route_id from bus_stops s1 
where exists(select 1 from bus_stops s2 where s1.route_id = s2.route_id and s2.stop_name = 'stop1')
and exists(select 1 from bus_stops s2 where s1.route_id = s2.route_id and s2.stop_name = 'stop2')
```

it will give you the routes that have both the stops.

Comment: Upvoted for posting the exact same solution, 4 seconds earlier :-)